# How to create a shortcut for an app from an other app in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a window's form application with c# that can copy an other application's shortcut to an especial folder.I use this code to copy files but cannot make a short cut...

```
system.io.file.copy("what","where");
```

I use this but it doesn't work

```
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(".\\calc.exe");
        string destination = @"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\Startup";
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.exe");

        foreach (var shorcut in files)
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(shorcut.FullName, destination);
        }
```

What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you to read the lnk file

It doesn't make a lot of sense, don't have an easy way to check it. I reckon the best approach is to read the .lnk file the way it is supposed to be read. You can use COM to do so, the ShellLinkObject class implements the IShellLink interface. Get started with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab and navigate to c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll. That generates an interop library. Write code like this:

```
public static string GetLnkTarget(string lnkPath) {
    var shl = new Shell32.Shell();         // Move this to class scope
    lnkPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lnkPath);
    var dir = shl.NameSpace(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath));
    var itm = dir.Items().Item(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lnkPath));
    var lnk = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;
    return lnk.Target.Path;
}
```

Then you simply save it in your own folder using the following code

```
First include a reference to C:\Windows\System32\wshom.ocx

Second, include the following using statement :-

using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

Third, Here is the code :-

// This creates a Folder Shortcut
IWshShell wsh = new WshShellClass();
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut) wsh.CreateShortcut (shortcutpathfilename);
shortcut.TargetPath = targetdir;
shortcut.Save();
shortcutpathfilename is a path & filename of the .lnk file.
targetdir is the directory the link points to.
```